# How do I build a controller filter override helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails you can add `before_filter`s to your controllers. Assuming a base controller has the following:

`before_filter :my_base_filter`

Given this, assume that you have a whole host of controllers that inherit from this base controller, and that the norm is that this behavior is correct. I now have a small handful of controllers that do the following:

```
skip_before_filter :my_base_filter, only: [:method1, :method2]
before_action only: [:method1, :method2] do
  my_secondary_filter(param1)
end
```

Given that this code is in a few of my controllers, and that the methods that are passed in (as well as whether or not it uses `only` or `except`) are different from one controller to the next, I would ideally like to have a single `before_action` or `before_filter` that I could call that would effectively run the above code. The call, in the inherited controller, would ideally look something like:

```
replace_filter(param1, {only: [:method1, :method2]})
```

The second parameter (the hash detailing which methods to apply it to) should be able to accept an empty value and apply to all methods. I have created a helper function that (is written alongside these other filters and), syntactically and logically should do this, but can't seem to properly invoke it using a `before_action` or `before_filter` without `my_base_filter` executing first. Is it possible to do something similar to this, and if so, what is the best way to do so?

---

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper

  before_action :my_base_filter
  ...
end
```

inherited_controller.rb

```
class InheritedController < ApplicationController

  # I want to replace these lines with my new helper function
  skip_before_filter :my_base_filter, only: [:method1, :method2]
  before_action only: [:method1, :method2] do
    my_secondary_filter(param1)
  end
  ...
end
```

application_helper.rb

```
class ApplicationHelper

  def my_base_filter
    # Do shit here that is the normal behavior
  end

  def my_secondary_filter(param1)
    # Do shit here that is specific to certain functions INSTEAD
    # of running the normal base filter
  end

  # I want to be able to simply call this function
  # as a before_action or before_filter in order
  # to DRY up my code
  def replace_filter(param1, methods = {})
    # Run validation on parameters (including methods) here
    # including raising exceptions if necessary
    ...
    # Then run the following
    skip_before_filter :my_base_filter, methods
    before_action(methods) do
      my_secondary_filter(param1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us what you wrote?

Comment: It's not code I can post here. I'll update the original post with more specific details.

Comment: @TarynEast I've added more specifics to the post, but I can't provide actual code.

Comment: I was referring specifically to this comment of yours:"  I have created a helper function that (is written alongside these other filters and), syntactically and logically should do this, but can't seem to properly invoke it using a before_action or before_filter without my_base_filter executing first. " - if you've had a go at writing the function... I'd love to see what you've got (even if it isn't working)... you can redact out any proprietary-sounding bits :)

Comment: So... what happens when you use replace_filter ? What errors do you get?

Comment: Assuming I replace the code in the inherited controller with `before_action :replace_filter, param1, only: [:method1, :method2]`, 
I get no errors - it just runs `my_base_filter` before it gets to `replace_filter`, and the whole point is to not have it run `my_base_filter`.

Comment: ok, this "helper" - is that in the helpers directory? Are you aware that helpers are intended for views, (not models or controllers)? Have you looked into "concerns"? If so - I reckon I have a plausible solution for you.

Comment: I have not specifically looked into concerns for controllers, though I do use them for models. And yes, the helper is in the helpers directory. Should I be making concerns, and using the `included do` functionality with a block that does just this? How would I pass in parameters including the methods, and alternate params to this?

Comment: Yeah, definitely don't use helpers for anything except for views... instead, create controllers/concerns and put your application concern there. Also: give it a real name - what does it *do* for you? Name it that :)

Comment: Ok, I've added a skeleton Concern for you - with a whole bunch of printf debugging - that will help you figure out what you need to alter next to get it properly working. Hopefully it's enough for that "aha" moment for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... there's this thing in Rails called a [Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html). It's intended to be the way you pull out modules of stuff in Rails - while allowing a whole bunch of neato things that you can use.

There's a number of articles out there on what they are and how to use them. I'll let you go explore.

I can't say for certain that the following will fix your problem, but it's how I'd approach it.

Part of your problem is that as you say - by the time you get to running your "replace_filter" method, the bas_filter method has already run.

What you need is to be able to run replace_filter on the first time that your ApplicationHelper is included into the Controller.

This is where `ActiveSupport::Concern`'s [`included`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveSupport/Concern/included) method comes to your aid.

Give something like this a try:

```
# give this a meaningful name...
class FilterStuff < ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    puts "I'm in included"
    # note: not the replace_filter, but the method that will call it
    if defined?(:replace_filter_method)
       puts "This controller defines replace filter method which I'm now calling"
      replace_filter_method
    else
      puts "this controller does not define the replace method and will default to base behaviour"
      before_action :my_base_filter   
    end
  end

  def my_base_filter
    puts "I'm in my base filter"
  end

  def my_secondary_filter(param1)
    puts "I'm in secondary filter with param: #{param1}"
  end

  # making this work is another problem...
  def replace_filter(param1, methods = {})
    puts "I'm in replace filter with: #{param1} and #{methods.inspect}"

    # Run validation on parameters (including methods) here
    # including raising exceptions if necessary
    ...
    # Then run the following
    skip_before_filter :my_base_filter, methods
    before_action(methods) do
      my_secondary_filter(param1)
    end
  end
end
class InheritedController < ApplicationController
   include FilterStuff

   # actions go here...

   private

   # define this method only on controllers that need it
   def replace_filter_method
     puts "I'm in this controllers replace filter method"
     replace_filter(param1, only: [:method1, :method2])
   end
end
```

I've added a whole bunch of printf debugging - have a run trhough and it'll tell you what is being called when - and that will help you determine what you need to do to get the proper stuff working.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I'm going to accept your response because I think it is the correct way to do this, though the easy way to do this is using `prepend_before_action` (see below) , and call `replace_filter` with it

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/prepend_before_filter

Comment: Which you choose depend on whether you want to write your own DSL for it - which really depends on how many times you're likely to be writing it in your controllers. for only a handful... maybe not worth the effort except as a learning-exercise.